# Django admin not showing users after user customization

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

I customized my user authentication. Using Django 3.

In models.py I have;

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_patient = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_dentist = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

In views.py I have below for user creation and login;

```
def create_account_dentist(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    #Create Dentist Type User
    username = request.POST.get('username')    
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    mobile_num = request.POST.get('mobilenum')
    user_profile = User()        
    user_profile.username = username
    user_profile.email = username
    user_profile.set_password(password)
    user_profile.is_dentist = True
    user_profile.is_staff = True
    user_profile.is_active = True
    user_profile.mobile_number = mobile_num
    user_profile.save()
    login(request, user_profile)
    return redirect(reverse('dentist-section'))
```

My sttings.py : AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User'

When i check /admin page i see only groups section.

[image]

But i want to see the users, permissions and user groups together.

My DB tables are :

auth_group,
auth_group_permissions,
auth_permission,
django_admin_log,
django_content_type,
django_migrations,
django_session,
myapp_dentist,
myapp_manager,
myapp_patient,
myapp_user,
myapp_user_groups,
myapp_user_user_permissions

Although i created users in myapp_user, i dont see and manage them in django admin page

Below is screeshot from myapp_user table :

[image]

Comment: did you registered in admin.py?

Comment: How do i do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the admin.py file which is under the user's model folder, isn't it contain the `admin.site.register(YUOR_MODEL_NAME)` ,if you want to view the data in `/admin` page must have registered.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from YOUR_APP_NAME.models import User


admin.site.register(User)
```

Comment: Now i can see. Thanks master.